# Checking node contents against a given set of values

Tags: xml, xpath

Given an XML document such as this:

```
<root>
    <foo>
        <bar>a</bar>
        <bar>b</bar>
        <bar>c</bar>
    </foo>
    ...
</root>
```

How can I retrieve all `foo`-nodes that have `bar`-subnodes with certain values?

So for instance, if I need all `foo`-elements that have `bar`-subelements with values `a` and `c`, I am currently using this expression:

```
//*/foo[bar/text()='a'][bar/text()='c']
```

which is fine, except that it gets clumsy if I have more "`bar`-constraints" and I'm not too big of a fan of programmatically generated XPath expressions :). What I am looking for is something along these lines (obviously invalid syntax):

```
//*/foo[bar/text() in-set('a', 'c')]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear if you want AND or OR there. Your XPath example with two filters is an AND (i.e. require that `foo` has both "a" and "c"), but comments to other replies seem to imply that you actually want an OR (any `foo` with either "a" or "c"). With XPath 2.0, the latter would be very easy:

```
//foo[bar[. = ('a', 'c')]]
```

AND is a bit trickier:

```
//foo[count(distinct-values(data(bar[. = ('a', 'c')])))) = 2]
```

or, if you would use variables (I'll show XQuery syntax, but in practice you should use your XPath implementation API to provide values for external variables):

```
let $values := ('a', 'c')
return //foo[count(distinct-values(data(bar[. = $values])))) = count($values)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
//*/foo[bar/text()='a' or bar/text()='c']
```

There is no 'in' operator in XPath. Here's a [list of xpath operators](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp).

Comment: Right, but that doesn't really help me. I would still have to programmatically create that sequence which, given enough constraints, can be pretty long.
Instead I'd rather just create the string `'a','b','c'` and not touch the XPath expression itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to XPath 2.0 you can use the [`matches` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches):

```
//foo[fn:matches(bar, "a|c")]
```

Unfortunately XPath 2.0 isn't that widely supported.

Tomalak's answer gave me an idea:

```
//foo[bar[fn:matches(text(),"a|c")]]
```

That might work, since it's not working on a node set but an individual text node.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but it seems that `matches()` does not accept a list as its first parameter.

Comment: Damn. Figures. The bottom line is XPath isn't good at this sort of thing. There is no simple way to do what you want without using multiple `[]` clauses or `or` conditions.

Comment: The second expression will match all `foo` nodes which have any `bar` node with either `"a"` or `"c"`. What's needed is to only match `foo` nodes which have _both_ `bar` with `"a"`, and another `bar` with `"c"`.

Answer (score 0):

For "AND" expressions you are more or less stuck with what you currently have. Though I'd write it as:

```
//*/foo[bar/text()='a' and bar/text()='c']
```

For "OR" expressions (your question is not clear on this) you can try with:

```
//*/foo[bar[contains(',a,c,', concat(',', text(), ','))]]
```

Or, more readably written:

```
//*/foo[
  bar[
    contains(
      ',a,c,', 
      concat(',', text(), ',')
    )
  ]
]
```

This finds `<foo>` elements that contain `<bar>` elements which *themselves* conform to a certain rule. And the rule is: "text value (enclosed in commas) is contained in the search string (enclosed in commas)".

For a text value of `'a'` and a search string of `'a,b'` you would look for `',a,'` within `',a,b,'`. So if any of the inner `<bar>` elements matches, the outer `<foo>` element is going to be selected.

You'd have to chose a delimiter that cannot be contained in the values, obviously. From your sample code, I chose `','` but any valid character will do.

Comment: Wouldn't this require the `bar`-elements to be in a specific order as well as me knowing that order ahead of time?

Answer (score 0):

You can be sneaky about it and add an element to your document like:

```
<values>
   <value>a</value>
   <value>c</value>
</values>
```

Then this XPath

```
/root/foo[count(bar[.=/root/values/value]) = count(/root/values/value)]
```

will find all `foo` elements where the number of `bar` children whose value is in your list of values equals the number of values in that list.  This will work - *if* all of the `bar` elements contain distinct values.